# How to plot a normal pdf in spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a probability density function of a set of datapoints, sampled from a normal distribution as following:

```
mu, sigma = 0, 1
N = 100000
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, N)
def normal_dist(x , mean , sd):
    prob_density = (np.pi*sd) * np.exp(-0.5*((x-mean)/sd)**2)
    return prob_density

pdf = normal_dist(s, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(s,pdf , color = 'red')
plt.xlabel('Data points')
plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
plt.show()
```

But this is the picture I get. I am interested in getting one line that represents the pdf. Where am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pyplot.plot` connects one point to the next point **in the order in which they occur**.  This is what you are seeing.  The order of your points is random, so you are seeing a bunch of connections between the random points.

Soring `s` should fix it: `s.sort()`